# How do I access the :id parameter in the route file in ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, url-routing, ember-cli

I have these routes in my Ember app:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('posts', function () {
    this.route('show',  {path: '/:id'});
  });
});
```

Let's focus on the `show` route with url `/posts/:id`
It uses the `PostsShowController` which looks like this:

```
import Ember from "ember";
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({});
```

And the route file `/routes/posts/show.js` which looks like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

var PostsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return posts[variable];
  }
});

var posts = ...
```

On the fifth line, where it says `posts[variable]` I want to replace `variable` with the **`:id`** parameter that gets passed in the url. So if I enter localhost:4200/posts/3 I want it to be 3. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you think through your routes. "/posts" implies that you're looking at all posts while "/post/:id" implies that you're looking at a post by a given id. So you likely want something like:

```
this.resource('posts');
this.resource('post', { path: 'post/:id' });
```

This would give you two routes:

- /posts
- /post/:id

You can then provide corresponding Ember Route objects as follows:

```
App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    // return all posts
  }
});

App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function (params) {
    // params.id will be the :id value from the route
    // return post by id
  }
});
```

Comment: The convention i'm using (with the plural, eg. `/posts/1`) is the same as the Rails convention. And I am building this app as a new feature extentsion of an existing Rails app so I want the URL naming conventions to match. Also, if it's good enough for Rails, its good enough for me

Comment: Fair enough, you can do whatever you'd like. Just remember that Ember is big on convention as well, especially with naming. So as long as you're consistent, you'll be fine.